# How to Use UI Options in Styles

Tags: c#, uwp, winui-3

I am passing parameters to UserControl. In the UserControl itself, there is a RadioButton to which the ToggleButton style is attached. In fact, in the style itself there are Text and Icon elements; they need to be passed a parameter, it must be bound via x: Bind. If I assign TargetType="local:MenuButton" it throws a XAML parsing error. If you use TemplateBinding it will throw an error global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Organazier.UserControls.MenuButton"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Organazier.UserControls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Background="Transparent">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <!--default icon-->
        <x:String x:Key="DefaultIcon">M4,2L4,22 12.683594,22C12.387594,21.378,12.181078,20.707,12.080078,20L12.074219,20C12.026219,19.673 12,19.34 12,19 12,15.474 14.609,12.566078 18,12.080078 18.327,12.033078 18.66,12 19,12 19.34,12 19.673,12.033078 20,12.080078L20,8 14,2 4,2z M13,3.4550781L18.5,9 13,9 13,3.4550781z M19,14C16.25,14 14,16.25 14,19 14,21.75 16.25,24 19,24 21.75,24 24,21.75 24,19 24,16.25 21.75,14 19,14z M19,16C19.461147,16,19.892436,16.114019,20.283203,16.300781L16.300781,20.285156C16.113553,19.893994 16,19.461758 16,19 16,17.346 17.346,16 19,16z M21.699219,17.716797C21.885981,18.107564 22,18.538853 22,19 22,20.654 20.654,22 19,22 18.538242,22 18.106006,21.886447 17.714844,21.699219L21.699219,17.716797z</x:String>

       
        <Style x:Key="MenuButtonStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#CCFFFFFF"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" CornerRadius="10" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Padding="{Binding Padding}">
                            
                            <Grid x:Name="myGrid">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <!--column for Icon-->
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <!--Column for Text-->
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

         <!-- There will be a link error -->
                                <Path Data="{x:Bind Icon, FallbackValue={StaticResource DefaultIcon}, TargetNullValue={StaticResource DefaultIcon}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      Stretch="Uniform"
                                      Height="30" Width="31" 
                                      Fill="#515EC1"/>
                                
                                     <!-- There will be a link error -->
                                     <TextBlock
                                          FontSize="20" 
                                          Grid.Column="1"
                                          Text="{x:Bind TextCustom}"
                                          />
                                    
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <!--now since we have radio button, there is a property "GroupName" which we can use for our benefit here..-->
    <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonStyle}"  
                 GroupName="{x:Bind GroupName}"
                 Command="{x:Bind TogleCommand}" 
                 CommandParameter="{x:Bind ItemName}"
                 />
</UserControl>
```

**Works in wpf**

```
Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=this, FallbackValue=MenuText, TargetNullValue=MenuText}"
```

---

```
<UserControl x:Class="Organaizer.UserControls.MenuButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Organaizer.UserControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" x:Name="this" Background="Transparent">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <PathGeometry x:Key="DefaultIcon" Figures="M4,2L4,22 12.683594,22C12.387594,21.378,12.181078,20.707,12.080078,20L12.074219,20C12.026219,19.673 12,19.34 12,19 12,15.474 14.609,12.566078 18,12.080078 18.327,12.033078 18.66,12 19,12 19.34,12 19.673,12.033078 20,12.080078L20,8 14,2 4,2z M13,3.4550781L18.5,9 13,9 13,3.4550781z M19,14C16.25,14 14,16.25 14,19 14,21.75 16.25,24 19,24 21.75,24 24,21.75 24,19 24,16.25 21.75,14 19,14z M19,16C19.461147,16,19.892436,16.114019,20.283203,16.300781L16.300781,20.285156C16.113553,19.893994 16,19.461758 16,19 16,17.346 17.346,16 19,16z M21.699219,17.716797C21.885981,18.107564 22,18.538853 22,19 22,20.654 20.654,22 19,22 18.538242,22 18.106006,21.886447 17.714844,21.699219L21.699219,17.716797z"/>

 
        <Style x:Key="MenuButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#CCFFFFFF"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{Binding Padding, ElementName=this}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <!--column for Icon-->
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>

                                    <!--Column for Text-->
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <!--the Fallbackvalue is used when the binding path is not correct or null so we can set default value to use instead of that in case.. like we are using default icon here.. and so does happen with Targetnullvalue.. when there is no value provided from source our binding will use default value-->
                                <Path Data="{Binding Icon, ElementName=this, FallbackValue={StaticResource DefaultIcon}, TargetNullValue={StaticResource DefaultIcon}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      Stretch="Uniform"
                                      Height="30" Width="31" 
                                      Fill="#515EC1"/>

                                <TextBlock  FontSize="20" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=this, FallbackValue=MenuText, TargetNullValue=MenuText}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
   

    <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonStyle}"  
GroupName="{Binding GroupName, ElementName=this}"          
Command="{Binding Path=TogleCommand, ElementName=this, Mode=OneWay}"
CommandParameter="{Binding ItemName, ElementName=this}"
                     />
   
    
    
</UserControl>
```

Comment: If you want to apply styles to your control, you should go with a Custom Control instead of User Control.

Comment: It's very unclear about what you want to get and what's the error you are getting now. Please share more details about what you are trying to implement.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding is there a link to an example?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT i want to use public variables for user control

Comment: I'm still very confused about what you are trying to do. Could you please give me a complete description of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT I want to pass an image and text to the style

Comment: You can't assign a `ToggleButton` style to a `RadioButton`. These are two different controls.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT in wpf i can do this. But how do I pass an image and text to the style?

Comment: Check my videos about [UserControls](https://youtu.be/AisI7MCVrC8) and [CustomControls](https://youtu.be/yrW6Yt3tC7g).

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding yes I saw the video.  I later show the source code on wpf.  I try to change part of the style

Comment: When converting from WPF to WinUI, you also changed `{Binding}` to `{x:Bind}`. `x:Bind` and `Binding` follow different rules, and it doesn't appear that you took those changes into account. One possibility is to stick with `{Binding}` in WinUI, and maybe convert from `{Binding}` to `{x:Bind}` as a separate step after you've verified that the WPF->WinUI conversion was successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the style of the radio button like adding some extra control and you want to use binding to pass data to it, you will need to create a custom radiobutton.

1. Create a new class file called **MyRadioButton**. Inherited from `Radiobutton`
2. Get the default style of the `RadioButton` and change its target type to **MyRadioButton**.
3. Apply that style in the **MyRadioButton** class by setting the `DefaultStyleKey` property
4. Create two DependencyProperties in the **MyRadioButton** class so you could use binding to pass data to the **MyRadioButton** class.
5. Go to the style for **MyRadioButton**. Add controls as you want which uses the new data.

Here is the simple sample I made, you could refer to this.

**MyRadioButton.cs**

```
 public class MyRadioButton :RadioButton
{
    public MyRadioButton()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyRadioButton);
        
        this.DataContext = this;
    }


    // create a string property 
    public string customText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(customTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(customTextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for customText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty customTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("customText", typeof(string), typeof(MyRadioButton), new PropertyMetadata(null,new PropertyChangedCallback(OncustomTextChanged)));
  
    // property changed
    private static void OncustomTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var value = e.NewValue;
        Debug.WriteLine("New Text Value get");
    }

    //create a image property
    public BitmapImage customImage
    {
        get { return (BitmapImage)GetValue(customImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(customImageProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for customImage.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty customImageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("customImage", typeof(BitmapImage), typeof(MyRadioButton), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OncustomImageChanged)));

    private static void OncustomImageChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var value = e.NewValue;
        Debug.WriteLine("New BitmapImage Value get");
    }
```

**MyRadioButton Style**

```
    <Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="local:MyRadioButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonForeground}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,6,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-7,-3,-7,-3"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseStrokePointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseFillPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseCheckedStrokePointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseCheckedFillPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonCheckGlyphFillPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonCheckGlyphStrokePointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonForegroundPressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBackgroundPressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseStrokePressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseFillPressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseCheckedStrokePressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseCheckedFillPressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonCheckGlyphFillPressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonCheckGlyphStrokePressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBackgroundDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderBrushDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseStrokeDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseFillDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseCheckedStrokeDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseCheckedFillDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonCheckGlyphFillDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonCheckGlyphStrokeDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Ellipse Grid.Column="0" x:Name="OuterEllipse" Fill="{StaticResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseFill}" Height="20" Stroke="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseStroke}" StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderThemeThickness}" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="20"/>
                            <Ellipse Grid.Column="0" x:Name="CheckOuterEllipse" Fill="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseCheckedFill}" Height="20" Opacity="0" Stroke="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseCheckedStroke}" StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderThemeThickness}" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="20"/>
                            <Ellipse Grid.Column="0" x:Name="CheckGlyph" Fill="{ThemeResource RadioButtonCheckGlyphFill}" Height="10" Opacity="0" Stroke="{ThemeResource RadioButtonCheckGlyphStroke}" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="10"/>
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid Height="32" Grid.Column="1">
                            
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding customText}" Width="60" Height="32"/>
                            <Image  Source="{Binding customImage}" Width="60" Height="32"/>

                        </Grid>
                        
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" 
                                          AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                          Grid.Column="2" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                          ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                          Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                          TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

**MainPage.Xaml**

```
    <Grid>

    <local:MyRadioButton x:Name="MyTestBUTTON" customText="{x:Bind testString}" customImage="{x:Bind targetimage}" Content="First Choice"/>

</Grid>
```

**MainPage.cs**

```
        public string testString { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage targetimage { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        targetimage = new BitmapImage();
        targetimage.UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/london.png");
        testString = "234";

    }
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Yes, it helped me to do what I wanted, thanks

Comment: A small instruction to those who came to the court.

1) Move styles to Themes/Generic.xaml
2) Create file in folder CustomControl/MyRadioButton.cs